# Remove noise after thinning algorithm (opencv)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, fingerprint

i am currently working on a biometric system based on fingerprints.

[Enhanced Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkV62.png)

[Image Skelet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an962.png)

As you can see in the thinned image, i get a lot of noise (which will translate to false minutiae).
The algorithm used in thinning is the Zhang Suen algorithm.
If anyone has a solution to this problem, please share it.
Thank you!

*EDIT*

It turns out the implemented Zhang Suen thinning algorithm does not follow the center of the ridge. It goes along the edges which results in false minutiae.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _noise_? The tiny branches?

Comment: @Rick M. , exactly, those tiny branches + some false bigger branches.